# Using HTTP with AWS API Gateway and Service Proxy

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, gateway

I seem to be forced in to using HTTPS with AWS API Gateway. I am only hosting non-sensitive GET requests that do not need to be https.

How do I setup HTTP GET Method?

I am using a custom domain name and pointing to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FAQ, this is not possible:

> [A]ll of the APIs created with Amazon API Gateway expose HTTPS endpoints only. Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP) endpoints.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/#general